# next-i18next, next export & 404 on non-generated pages (with fallback true/blocking)

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, next-i18next

Having followed the documentation on [i18next/next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) to configure i18n and then the instructions on [this locize blog post](https://locize.com/blog/next-i18n-static/) on how to export static sites with `next export`, I am able to export localised versions of each page.

The problem is that pages that have not been statically generated return a 404, despite setting `fallback: true` in the `getStaticPaths` return object. The page works on my localhost but not when deployed with Vercel.

Code:

```
const ArticlePage: NextPageWithLayout<Props> = ({ article }: Props) => {
    const { i18n, t } = useTranslation('page/news/article')

    const router = useRouter()

    if (router.isFallback) return <div>Loading...</div>

    return <div>Article</div>
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    let paths: { params: { aid: string; locale: TLocale } }[] = []

    try {
        const response = await api.get(`/articles?per_page=9999`)
        const articles = response.data.data as IArticle[]

        articles.forEach((a) => {
            getI18nPaths().forEach((p) => {
                paths.push({
                    params: {
                        aid: a.base_64_id,
                        locale: p.params.locale,
                    },
                })
            })
        })

        return {
            paths,
            fallback: true,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            paths,
            fallback: true,
        }
    }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale, params }) => {
    try {
        const article = await api.get(`/articles/${params?.aid}`)

        return {
            props: {
                ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale || 'en', [
                    'footer',
                    'header',
                    'misc',
                    'page/news/index',
                    'page/news/article',
                ])),
                article: article.data as IArticle,
            },
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
}

ArticlePage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
    return <Layout>{page}</Layout>
}

export default ArticlePage
```

```
"i18next": "22.4.9",
"next-i18next": "^13.1.5",
"react-i18next": "^12.1.5",
```

There is a warning in the console `react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next` when entering an non-generated page (alongside the not-found error of course). An issue raised about this warning is interesting but I could not find an answer to my issue within: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/1917.

Attempts to fix:

- adding `revalidate: 10` to the return object of `getStaticProps`
- using `fallback: 'blocking'`
- trying a few different variants of `localePath` in `next-i18next.config` including the recommendation featured here: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#vercel-and-netlify
- adding `react: { useSuspense: false }` to `next-i18next.config`
- combinations of the above

Answer (score 1):

`next export` does not support `fallback: true` as per their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#next-export). I should've been using `next build` - this too will generate static HTML at build time whilst also supporting runtime fetching if the resource does not exist.